# Viewpager children elevation effect doesn't overflow

Tags: android, android-viewpager, elevation

I'm developing an android app where i implement a viewpager that takes a fragment as a child view, but I want the child fragment to have an elevation's shadow effect to overflow other viewgroups (or basically to be elevated all over the app just like a FloatingActionButton). I come from web development background, and I thought I can achieve a shadow overflow.

So Image #1 is what i want to achieve, but i got image #2 while testing the app

#1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeFy4.png
#2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mBPV.jpg

Comment: Show your code and xml for what you have

Comment: @Andrew thnkx for reply. I already managed to get fragment container to match parent to achieve the lower shadow. However, still can't get the Viewpager to overflow the elevation shadow on the Tablayout (in which its XML code is beside the viewpager XML). As per the code and xml, im sorry as this app is a Bank's property as I can't show or even copy the code. Im working remotely and they can see what i do